# Using Taylor's Theorem to expect maximum error

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose that we use $p(x) = 1 + x + \frac {x^2} 2$ as an approximation for $f(x) = e^x$ on the interval (-.5, .5). What's the maximum error we can expect.

I know that Taylor's Theorem states

Let $\alpha,$ $\beta$ be distinct points in [a,b], $\alpha$ $\neq$ $\beta$ , and $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{ (f^{(k)})(\alpha) } {k!}(t-\alpha)^k$$

Then there exists a point x between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that 
$$ f(\beta) = P(\beta) + \frac{ (f^{(n)})(x) } {n!}(\beta - \alpha)^n$$

I also know that $\frac{ (f^{(n)})(x) } {n!}(\beta - \alpha)^n$ will give us the error term my real question is what do I substitute in for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is it the -.5 and .5 respectively or 0 and .5 respectively. Also I am curious about what is n in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the Taylor expansion for $e^x$ at the point $x=0$ to the order $2$:

$$e^x|_{x=0}=1\\(e^x)'|_{x=0}=1,\\(e^x)''|_{x=0}=1,$$

hence $$e^x = e^x|_{x=0}+ x (e^x)'|_{x=0}=1 +\frac{x^2}{2}(e^x)''|_{x=0} + \frac{x^3}{3!}(e^x)'''|_{x=\xi}  $$with $\xi\in[0,x]$ for positive $x$ and $\xi \in [x,0]$ for negative $x$.

Simplify this expression: $$e^x=1+x+x^2/2+e^{\xi}\frac{x^3}{6}.$$
$x\in[-1/2,1/2]$, hence $\xi\in[-1/2,1/2]$ and $\sup_{x\in[-1/2,1/2]}|e^{\xi}\frac{x^3}{6}|\le \frac {1}{48 }e^{1/2}$.

Comment: I'm sorry can you elaborate anymore on this. I understand the first portion of what you did for the taylor expansion for x = 0 going to the second derivative. Where I'm lost is where you used $\xi \in[-1/2,1/2] where did \alpha and \beta$ go?